# slideDown() in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want a simple effect of slide up and down. I'm new to jquery and I tried th following code, but it's not working

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fade li:first-child').css('display','none');
    $('#fade li:second-child').click(function() {
        $('#fade li:first-child').slideDown();          
    })  
})
</script>
```

Html

```
<ul id="fade">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

Please help, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#fade li:first-child').css('display','none');

        $('#fade li').click(function(){


            $('#fade li:first-child').slideDown();

            })  
        })
```

Answer (score 2):

error in this line:

```
$('#fade li:second-child')
```

use  :nth-child(2) selector to fetch 2-nd element or $('#fade li').eq(1)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#fade li:first-child').css('display','none');

    $('#fade li:nth-child(2)').click(function(){

        $('#fade li:first-child').slideDown();

        })  
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var mySlider = function( toggle, obj )
  {
    toggle.click(function(e){
      if( !obj.is( ':visible' ) )
      {
          obj.slideDown();
      }
      else
      {
          obj.slideUp();
      }
    });
  }

  var slide_toggle = $('#fade li:nth-child(2)');
  var menu = $('#fade li:first-child');
  menu.css( 'display', 'none' );

  mySlider( slide_toggle, menu );
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you missing `<script type='text/javascript'>` I did not found anything wrong with your code.

Comment: I think he wants it to slide up and down on click events.

Comment: hi there is no pseudo class :second-child in child selectors therefore your answer is wrong.